# Matrix norm used in Lipschitz condition on multidimensional SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, normed-spaces, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am studying multidimensional SDEs on the form
$$
 dX_t = a(X_t, t) dt + b(X_t, t) dW_t
$$
where $a$ is a vector valued function and $b$ is a matrix valued function. All calculations are performed in a standard (multidimensional) Euclidean space.
What norm is used on the matrix $b$ in the Lipschitz condition
$$
\| a(x,t)-a(y,t) \| + \| b(x,t)-b(y,t) \| \leq K \| x-y \| ?
$$
I haven't been able to find is directly spelled out. Regarding $\| a(x,t)-a(y,t) \|$ I assume it is just the Euclidean norm.

The particular Lipschitz condition is taken from Monte Carlo Methods in Financial Engineering by Paul Glasserman, appendix B.2 on SDEs.

Comment: By equivalence of matrix norms, it doesn't matter too much which particular norm you choose. It's only going to change the Lipschitz constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will state here the initial part of the fundamental theorem of **existence and uniqueness of stochastic differential equations** taken from Oksendal (Th. 5.2.1.).

*Let $T>0$ and $b(\cdot,\cdot):[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\sigma(\cdot,\cdot):[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ be measurable functions satisfying
$$|b(t,x)|+|\sigma(t,x)|\leq C(1+|x|), \ \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}^n,t \in [0,T]$$
for some constant $C$ **and where** $|\sigma|^2=\sum |\sigma_{ij}|^2$ and such that
$$|b(t,x)-b(t,y)|+|\sigma(t,x)-\sigma(t,y)|\leq D|x-y|$$
For some constant $D$. Let (...)*

I think this answers yours question.

Comment: Thank you so much. It gives exactly what I was looking for.